# REST and CSOM much slower than List Web Service

Tags: 2010, web-services, rest, client-object-model

lists.asmx = Web Service
listdata.svc = REST API
client.svc = CSOM

Using JavaScript to query a list using the 3 available APIs, I'm finding `lists.asmx` responds much faster than `listdata.svc` or `client.svc`. For all three queries, I'm setting the **ViewFields** and/or `$select` properties to pull only 3 fields from the list which has about 400 items

I see this trend on my local SP2010 VM, and the SP2010 servers my company has deployed.

```
API            Size     Timeline
lists.asmx     46KB     131ms
listdata.svc   12.5KB   889ms
client.svc     40KB     326ms
```

What's going on? Why would these two new (to 2010) APIs be slower?

Comment: under what conditions? does order matter? did the second execution of any method return different results? benchmarking is tricky.

Comment: Very interesting data. I suppose we'd need to run similar queries in multiple environments against different sources to be sure, but the numbers feel right based on my experience. If you think about the transformations which must occur under the covers (none of which are "free"), it makes some sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try to limit your query: Use the **ViewFieldsOnly** flag. Be sure that it is set! You can use the CAML query builder to check your queries: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/458008/CAML-Query-Builder

Answer (score 1):

Alway use filters for indexed columns first, like

```
Query = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>1</Value></Geq</Where>"
```

that will increase performance. So query with indexed field `ID` faster then without.